# is there a way to trigger a password reset to the current password in AD?

Tags: active-directory, password, g-suite, google

I'm running Google apps password sync, but it only triggers on a "password change" event.
All our users are managed from a remote database which syncs AD to it via a service, using `dsmod` to manage AD.

Is there a way that I can tell AD to 'reset' each password to the current password (ie, no change), forcing the GAPS sync?

Re-running the sync via service is not triggering GAPS.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't a way to do what you're asking.

Google Apps Password Sync (GAPS) is merely a [Password Filter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms721882%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with a component that speaks to Google Apps. You either need to reset (an administrative action) passwords, or change (a user-initiated action) them to trigger GAPS. Without an AD password change or reset event, the filter is never touched, and therefore nothing will be sent to Google.